# how would I break this index in smaller, appengine query-planner-like?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this index:

```
<datastore-index kind="Invoices" ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="accountId" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="deleteStatus" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="status" direction="asc"/>
    <property name="date" direction="desc"/>
    <property name="number" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

... and many more like this one where changes only the direction of the status, date or number or simply instead of status there is counterpartId, or another index. Anyway, there are far too many indexes for this kind (28). I want to reduce the number by using the new appengine query planner. How would you break this index down?
Here are all the indexes I am using currently:
[image: indexes to split]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to approach this you need too know what kinds of queries you're doing, then you can remove the indexes that you're not querying with.  It's hard to answer with what you've given.

You might end up with a lot of indexes if you've changed your code a lot and have issued various sorts of queries for this kind.  You can get rid of old indexes for queries you are no longer using.

Comment: SELECT * FROM Invoices where accountId = 'someid' a

Comment: I have double checked and I don't have unused indexes for this kind, but since I have to cover all possibilities of a search menu, there are a lot of indexes, which seem to me could be compacted by using the query planner.

Comment: Check out the image above. Those are all indexes and since it is one index per query, you can deduce the queries too. Now could you tell me how could I split those indexes in smaller ones? Thanks ;)

Comment: Image isn't working.  And is there more to the query?  Seems like the only thing you need indexed is accountId.

Comment: Though your comments above are broken, it seems like you get the main idea.  You need one index per query.  It's a question of whether you can break your queries to smaller ones to use a smaller set of indexes.

Comment: Actually, since the query planner, you can define reutilizable indexes. Check this out: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection